# Use image capture result in dialogfragment

Tags: android

I'm working on a project which I need to capture image and show it's preview in 
a dialog fragment

the dialog fragment class is as below:

```
    public class DataImportDialog extends DialogFragment {

            /******************************
             * Capture management controls
             * *************************
             ****************************/
            // Activity request codes
            private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
            public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;


            // directory name to store captured images and videos
            private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "MapirImages";

            private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

            private ImageView imgPreview;

            private Button btnCapturePicture;
         @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(R.string.ERROR)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.business_register,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        click(getView());
                                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, getActivity().getIntent());
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.business_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, getActivity().getIntent());
                            }
                        })

                        .create();
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_import, null);
                builder.setView(v);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);

            /*
             * Capture image button click event
             */
            btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // capture picture
                    captureImage();

    //                click(getView());
                }

                });

            // Checking camera availability
            if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // will close the app if the device does't have camera

            }
            return builder;
        }
/*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /*
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }  else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        // If the activity we're being attached to has
        // not implemented the OnDialogDoneListener
        // interface, the following line will throw a
        // ClassCastException. This is the earliest we
        // can test if we have a well-behaved activity.
        try {
            OnDialogDoneListener test = (OnDialogDoneListener) act;
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            // Here is where we fail gracefully.
//            Log.e(MainActivity.LOGTAG, "Activity is not listening");
        }
        super.onAttach(act);
    }
```

Now when I capture the image and approve it, I can not get the result of image capture in the dialogFragmnet class. Actually I implemented a OnActivityResult like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the fragment that I load dialogFragment on it, if the user long click on a point on the map, the dialog will be appeared and he can take a photo related to that point, and I want to show a preview of the taken photo on the same dialog fragment:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    OnMarkerClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {
static final int PICK_EDIT_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int DIALOG_FRAGMENT = 1;
private Context mContext = null;
private GoogleMap mMap = null;
private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
private String mLocString = null;
private Marker mLastClicked;
boolean markerClicked;
private float mAccuracy = 0;
private LatLng mLatLng = null;
DataImportDialog pdf;


public static MyMapFragment newInstance() {
    MyMapFragment myMF = new MyMapFragment();
    return myMF;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        getMapAsync(this);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext, this, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    doWhenEverythingIsReady();
}

private void doWhenEverythingIsReady() {
    if(mMap == null || mLocString == null)
        return;
    mMap.clear();
    // Setup the info window for the marker
    CustomInfoWindowAdapter ciwm = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(mContext, mLocString);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(ciwm);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    // Add the marker to the map
    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
            .draggable(false)
            .flat(true)
            .position(mLatLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
    mLastClicked = mMap.addMarker(markerOpt);
    mLastClicked.showInfoWindow();



    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 16));

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

    mLatLng = point;
    markerClicked = false;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    pdf = DataImportDialog.newInstance("Enter Something");
    pdf.setTargetFragment(this, DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putDouble("Lat", point.latitude);
    args.putDouble("Lng", point.longitude);
    pdf.setArguments(args);
    pdf.show(ft, "PROMPT_DIALOG_TAG");
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    List<Address> here = null;
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Got connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    FusedLocationProviderApi locator = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    Location myLocation = locator.getLastLocation(mClient);
    // Toast.makeText(context, "My location is "+myLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    double lat = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double lng = myLocation.getLongitude();
    mAccuracy = myLocation.getAccuracy();

    mLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(mContext);
    try {
        here = geo.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mLocString = "Your current location:"
            + "\n" + here.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
            + "\n" + here.get(0).getAddressLine(1)
            + "\n" + here.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

    doWhenEverythingIsReady();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connection suspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // isInfoWindowShown() is broken so we need to keep track of what is
    // showing ourselves. See this issue report for details:
    // https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5408
    if (mLastClicked != null && mLastClicked.equals(marker)) {
        mLastClicked = null;
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        return true;
    } else {
        mLastClicked = marker;
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Got a map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMap = arg0;
    doWhenEverythingIsReady();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mClient.disconnect();
    if(mMap != null)
        mMap.clear();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case DIALOG_FRAGMENT:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLng).title(mLatLng.toString()));
                // After Ok code.
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                // After Cancel code.
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

}

inside the DataImportDialog class but it wasn't fired after approvement of the image capture.

Comment: Where to put this line of code?

Comment: And where to get the result?

Comment: can you post the relevent activity code also .....

Comment: sorry bro  Why you posting MyMapFragment  ... i want the activity code that  you placed onActivityResult

Comment: This is the fragment that I load dialogFragment on it, if the user long click on a point on the map, the dialog will be appeared and he can take a photo related to that point, and I want to show a preview of the taken photo on the same dialog fragment

Comment: man you want result in your Activty calss ..right?  not in MyMapFragment  class right?

Comment: No I want the result in the dialog to show the preview inside it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105433/discussion-between-saeed-and-amin-mohammadi).

Answer (score 1):

**use**

```
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

place your `onActiviyuresult` in side DataImportDialog fragment

```
   @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                    // successfully captured the image
                    // display it in image view
                    previewCapturedImage();
                } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // user cancelled Image capture
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    // failed to capture image
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I need a place to get the result of image capturing dialog, such as onActivityResult in ordinary activity class

Comment: Tnx man, but it didn't work, I tried to get the result in OnActivityResult of the parent activity.